# Get the max value from a slice of a JSON Array?

Tags: postgresql, json, array, postgresql-11

I would like to get the max value within a slice of a Json object (typicaly `[1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10]`) which is contained in a field named `Data` of the table `raw`.

The limits `Start` & `End` of the slice are contained in an other Json object named `Features` contained in a table named `features`

Here is the input:

```
CREATE TABLE raw (
    id     int PRIMARY KEY
      GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY

    data   json
);

INSERT INTO raw (data) VALUES
  ('[1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10]');

CREATE TABLE features (
    id         int,
    features   json
);

INSERT INTO features (id, features) VALUES
  (1, '{"Start" : 1, "End": 5}');
```

The output I would like is `7`, i.e. the max value of the slice [2,3,5,6,7]

Here is what I came up with looking at other posts, but it does not work...

```
SELECT
    R."ID",
    F."Features"->>'Start' AS Start, 
    F."Features"->>'End' AS End,
    sort_desc((array(select json_array_elements(R."Data")))[F."Features"->>'Start':F."Features"->>'End'])[1] as maxData
FROM 
    raw AS R
INNER JOIN 
    features AS F ON R."ID" = F."ID"
```

The approximate error message I get is concerning `sort_desc` :

> No function corresponding to this name or this type of arguments. You
>   should convert the type of data

Comment: That's a horrible schema for this kind of query. At the very least, use `jsonb`, even better don't use json, use an `int[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unnest json array:

Postgres [WITH ORDINALITY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

> When a function in the FROM clause is suffixed by WITH ORDINALITY, a bigint column is appended to the output which starts from 1 and increments by 1 for each row of the function's output. This is most useful in the case of set returning functions such as unnest().

Have a look at this answer of [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter):

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/3270427)

```
  SELECT
     r."ID",
     MAX(t.elem::int) MaxElem
  FROM   
      raw r
  JOIN
      features f
      ON f."ID" = r."ID"
  JOIN LATERAL
      json_array_elements_text(r."Data")
      WITH ORDINALITY AS t(elem, n) ON TRUE
  WHERE
      n >= (f."Features"->>'Start')::int + 1 
      AND 
      n <= (f."Features"->>'End')::int + 1
  GROUP BY
      r."ID";
```

> ```
> ID | maxelem
> -: | ------:
>  1 |       7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=79503ac1832d92b5826d086aa84f322b)*

Or if you prefer to use intarray module:

```
SELECT
    r."ID",
    (sort_desc(((ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements_text(r."Data")))::int[])[(f."Features"->>'Start')::int + 1:(f."Features"->>'End')::int + 1]))[1]
FROM
    raw r
JOIN
    features f
    ON f."ID" = r."ID";
```

*rextester [here](https://rextester.com/UCWB98351)*

Comment: I upvoted for doing what he wanted, but there is something to be said here for not doing this at all lol

Answer (score 2):

This is all around a horrible schema. You shouldn't be using `json` (as compared with `jsonb`) at all, ever (practically). If you're querying on the field, it should be `jsonb`. In your case, that's still a bad idea though, you likely want an sql array..

```
CREATE TABLE raw (
    raw_id   int  PRIMARY KEY
      GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    data     int[]
);

INSERT INTO raw (data) VALUES ('{1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10}');

CREATE TABLE features (
    feature_id   int REFERENCES raw,
    low          smallint,
    high         smallint
);

INSERT INTO features ( feature_id, low, high ) VALUES ( 1, 1, 5 );
```

Now you can query it like this, **note remember sql is 1-based**,

```
SELECT max(unnest)
FROM raw
CROSS JOIN features AS f
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(data[f.low:f.high]);
```

---

Also check out the `intarray` module, because it'll optimize the above,

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;

SELECT max(unnest)
FROM raw
CROSS JOIN features AS f
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(subarray(data,f.low,f.high-f.low+1))
```

You can further optimize this if you know you just need the last element of the array.

---

*Note if this is a GIS problem, you're still probably doing it wrong, but at least this method is sane.*

Comment: Now it is said. Nice answer. But I think `subarray` requires `start, lenght`. `subarray(data,f.low,f.high-f.low+1)`

Comment: Good catch! @McNets

Comment: I just started my project and using Postgre, so I did not know about that `int[]` type. Indeed, it seems way more adapted than Json in this case. I'll have a look at it to change the schema while I still can!